# Как получить access_token после редиректа на blank.html

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, cordova

Пишу приложение на Cordova, используя JS. Понадобилось использовать VK API, но вот незадача. Используя данную ссылку (убрал client_id)

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html&scope=groups,messages,offline&response_type=token&v=5.131&state=123456
```

Нельзя сменить redirect_uri на другой, ибо необходим доступ к сообщениям.

Как после редиректа на blank.html получить access_token, используя JS и HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Решено! Я стал использовать InAppBrowser для авторизации пользователя